# How do I modify the labels of data in Plotly (with Python, no pandas)?

Tags: python, graph, plotly-python

I have 3 series that I'm graphing, with the following code:

```
fig = px.line(x=x, y=[arrayA, arrayB, arrayC])
fig.show()
```

`arrayA`, `arrayB`, and `arrayC` are all numpy arrays. How can I modify the labels of these arrays, in both the legend and the mouseover popup? Right now, it labels my data as `wide_variable_0`, `wide_variable_1`, etc. (I'm not even sure what a "wide variable" is.) All the solutions I've found online seem to assume that I'm using pandas, which I am *not*.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually easier to create plots in python (pandas, matplotlib, seaborn and yes, plotly as well) if the data is provided as a dataframe. Your arrays, if provided as a dataframe, will be easily plotted (and the legend and hover labels automatically set correctly). Below is the code to do this....

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

### My random data creation and assigning to arrays ###
x=list(range(1,16))
arrayA = np.random.randint(100, size=(15))
arrayB = np.random.randint(100, size=(15))
arrayC = np.random.randint(100, size=(15))

### Creating a dataframe from the 3 arrays ###
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['arrayA']*len(x),'x': x,'y': arrayA})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['arrayB']*len(x),'x': x,'y': arrayB})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['arrayC']*len(x),'x': x,'y': arrayC})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])

### Plot using plotly express ###
fig = px.line(df, x='x', y='y', color = 'name', markers = True)
fig.show()
```

**Output plot**

[image]

**OPTION 2 - NO pandas**
If you do NOT want to use `pandas` at all AND have to use `plotly.express`, then this is one option. Note that you will need to provide the conversion array (new_names) like below....

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
x=list(range(1,16))
arrayA = np.random.randint(100, size=(15))
arrayB = np.random.randint(100, size=(15))
arrayC = np.random.randint(100, size=(15))

fig = px.line(x=x, y=[arrayA, arrayB, arrayC])

newnames = {'wide_variable_0':'A', 'wide_variable_1': 'B', 'wide_variable_2': 'C'}
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = newnames[t.name], legendgroup = newnames[t.name], 
                                      hovertemplate = t.hovertemplate.replace(t.name, newnames[t.name])))
fig.show()
```

**Graph**

[image]

**OPTION 3 - Using go**
If you are ok using the more generic `plotly.graph_objects` scatter plot with lines or lines_markrs to create the same. Advantage here is that the names come in directly, but need to use go.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
x=list(range(1,16))
arrayA = np.random.randint(100, size=(15))
arrayB = np.random.randint(100, size=(15))
arrayC = np.random.randint(100, size=(15))

# Create traces
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=arrayA,
                    mode='lines', name='A'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=arrayB,
                    mode='lines+markers', name='B'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=arrayC,
                    mode='lines+markers', name='C'))
fig.show()
```

**Graph**

[image]

Comment: While appreciated, I'm really trying to stay away from pandas. Making all the data frames is too much of a pain, and it's worth living without the nice names to avoid all the code bloat.

Comment: @AdamSmith - Added 2 options of doing this without pandas. See if these work